# parameters on mdx query using WITH MEMBER

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

well i have one "`member monthname as ()`" for every month

here a part of my query

```
member Diciembre as
(
([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[@anioact].&[12],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[@cedis],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])
-([Dim Tiempos].[Año-Mes].[Año].&[@anioant].&[12],([Measures].[venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[@cedis],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt])


)

select {Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septiembre,Octubre,Noviembre,Diciembre} on columns,
FILTER(
{[Dimrutas].[Ruta].Members},
(([Measures].[Venta]),[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[@cedis],[Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt]) > 0
)ON ROWS

from CuboBebidas
where ([Dimproductos].[Categoria].&[Agua 20 Lt],[Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[@cedis])
```

if i dont use parameters it work ok!
for now i need pass it to report services and i'll need parameters

you could see i have @nameparameter where i'll need these parameters but it doesn't work
only as it.

```
@anioact= user will one year
@anioant= @anioact-1
@cedis=a intenger number
```

then how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in MDX queries for SSRS may be a pain in the [whatever]. My recommendation is to build a string with those parameters. The query should look as follow :

```
="member ... [Dimregion].[Puntovta].&[" & Parameters!cedis.Value & "] ..."
```

Hope this helped!